# Routine Document creation with variable number of fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, documentation

I'd like advice on the best way to automate very routine document creation. The documents will typically be step by step instructions with a header and footer. Header and footer fields are constant for all documents. However, the meat of the document is step by step instructions. The number of steps will vary by document. Additionally, documents are divided into large general steps with smaller substeps. The number of general and smaller steps can vary. E.g. you could have 3 large steps consisting of 3, 8, and 20 smaller steps respectively. The smaller steps  need to also have the option of an associated image with them.  The current system used is formatted excel documents that we print to PDF for the final copy. It's a nightmare to keep the formatting clean and I want to fix it.

I think I'd ideally like something like a form that can be filled out by a user, prompting for all of the standard fields to fill up the header, before letting them enter a variable number of numbered steps with options to add a picture for that step. Then if the form could spit info into a formatted template, then that would be amazing. I'm not sure if Office has the tools to really do this or if I need to look elsewhere. Any advice would be great to get me on the right track. Forms to templates seems really doable from what I've been looking at but the idea of an expandable form with variable number of steps seems like a big roadblock. My main thing in general is having super easy text input from the user with an option for images. Then the template/form/system takes that input in a formats it into a pristine document with standardized formatting.

**Edit:** Alright here's my attempt at a bit of a narrower question. See this link first: https://ms-office-training.de/en/word-letter-template-with-control-elements/.  So what that accomplishes is a template with controlled fields. Only those fields can be edited by the user and the format is perfectly set. It can then be used over and over for many new and very similar documents. In theory, I could make a format that I like in word with tables and all to closely match my existing format. However, that's missing some important things that I would need. The number of fields is set and the formatting for the whole document is set in stone. What I would want is a way to easily expand the number of fields without end user input into the template; i.e. every time you need a new step to be added, add a new field to the template. Next, the template needs to be able to accommodate user inputted pictures. How would I go about building this in word/excel? Or would I need a different program for that?

For the form part of my question, I believe something like microsoft flow could take an MS form and pass the responses into a template with defined fields. See something like this:https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/building-scratch-forms-responses/.

Comment: Hi and welcome to superuser! Please take a moment (if not done yet) to look at the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and the [help section](https://superuser.com/help). From those resources it should be clear that your question is waaaaay to broad and has an "I-have-this-problem-solve-it-for-me" attitude.
I think it's an interesting question, but please edit it to only ask one thing and show your research. 
E.g. you could ask a question on how to collect data from your users and then show that you've tried `option A` but that did not fulfill your requirements to include images.

Comment: On the subject of making pristine documents with standardized formatting: check out [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/). [This question on anoter SE site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198026/13134) is related to your problem.

I look forward to see your well defined questions (with some prior research) on this topic.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking for... So narrow my question down and provide links showing the research I've done yes? Guilty as charged on the attitude thing; I've been halfheartedly googling for solutions for months to fix my frustration with the current system I use. Thank you.

Comment: :) Your name also hinted at some frustration. I would say split it into two questions, one about collecting a variable amount of info from users and one about placing a variable amount of info into a pre-formatted document. 
The reason I ask for research of is because this will often lead you onto possible solutions.

Comment: Gotcha, I edited OP but I'll also try and make it more concise for two separate posts. Thank you : ).

Comment: I've done something similar with Powershell taking input and shoving it into an Excel file, formatting it, and saving it out as PDF.  But it is a lengthy program to create start to finish.